# How to disable journaling on an HFS+ HDD in Ubuntu without using a Mac?

Tags: ubuntu, hfs, journaling, journaled

How to disable  journaling on an HFS+ HDD in Ubuntu without using a Mac?

Comment: journelling is a function of the filesystem.  it's either a case of a) can disable with a mount option, or b) can't disable under linux without reformatting the partition.

Comment: I hope that, if you find a solution, you come back here to answer this. :P

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to find a couple of programs written in C for this. Here are a couple of links to start you in the right direction:

- http://dmunsie.wordpress.com/code/hacks/
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1420673 : Forum post about this, looks like it's what you're looking for

To compile a c program, do this:

`gcc program.c` where program.c is the file that you want to compile.

You'll probably need the build-essential package in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**Remember**- make sure to back up any important information before messing with stuff, especially before you use code you find on the internet